# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='./css/style.css'>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/dataTable.css'>

<?php

    include("config.php");
    include("meniu.php");
    include("meniuV.php");
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf8' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf8' src='//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js'></script>";

    session_start();

?>
<div id="bilet" class="BiletCSS">

</div>
<?php

    $sql="SELECT * FROM meciuri WHERE data='2015-01-10'";
    $resursa=mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$resursa)
    {
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($resursa)==0)
    {
        print 'Nu s-a gasit niciun rezultat!<br>'; 
    }
    echo "<div class='ziua1image'>";
    echo "<img src='./images/fotbal2.jpg' style='width:600px;height:300px'>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class='div'>";
    echo "<table  id='tabelMeciuri' class='display' cellspacing='0'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr class='data_cota'>";
    echo "<td>Uefa Champions League</td>";
    echo "<td>1</td>";
    echo "<td>X</td>";
    echo "<td>2</td>";
    echo "<td>1x</td>";
    echo "<td>x2</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    $resursa=mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resursa))
    {
        $idConta1=$row['id_meci']."_1";
        $idConta2=$row['id_meci']."_2";
        $idConta3=$row['id_meci']."_3";
        $idConta4=$row['id_meci']."_4";
        $idConta5=$row['id_meci']."_5";
        $meci1=$row['nume_meci'];
            print' <tr class="ooddd">
                    <td>' .$row['nume_meci'] . '</td> 
                    <td><label id="'.$idConta1.'" onclick="getCota('.$row['id_meci'].','.$meci1.',1)" >' .$row['victorie_1'] . '</label></td>
                    <td><label id="'.$idConta2.'" onclick="getCota('.$row['id_meci'].',2)" >' .$row['egal_x'] . '</td>
                    <td><label id="'.$idConta3.'" onclick="getCota('.$row['id_meci'].',3)" >' .$row['victorie_2'] .'</td>
                    <td><label id="'.$idConta4.'" onclick="getCota('.$row['id_meci'].',4)" >' .$row['victorie_egal_1x'] .'</td>
                    <td><label id="'.$idConta5.'" onclick="getCota('.$row['id_meci'].',5)" >' .$row['victorie_egal_x2'] .'</td>
                </tr>';
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
?>


<script>
function getCota(id,numeMeci,index){
debugger;
    var idCota="#"+id+"_"+index;
    var idCota2=id+"_"+index;
    $("#bilet").append("<div id='optiune'><label>"+$(numeMeci).text()+"</label> <label>"+$(idCota).text()+"</label> </div>");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabelMeciuri').DataTable();
} );
</script>

<style>
.BiletCSS{
    width: 350pxpx;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#989898;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
</style>
```

I want to select one name and one number from database and put them in a separate div, next to the table.
When i try to select only the number (' .$row['egal_x'] . ') it works but if i want to add the name (' .$row['victorie_1'] . ') i don't get anything in that div and it shows me that error...
Can someone tell me how i can can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to insert `PHP`results in to a `JavaScript` String, you must build a string.

Change

```
<td><label id="'.$idConta1.'" onclick="getCota('.$row['id_meci'].','.$meci1.',1)" >' .$row['victorie_1'] . '</label></td>
```

to

```
<td><label id="'.$idConta1.'" onclick="getCota(\''.$row['id_meci'].'\',\''.$meci1.'\',1)" >' .$row['victorie_1'] . '</label></td>
```

otherwise the result of it is passed as name:

```
 // your code:
 onclick="getCota(Shakhtar ,meci,1)"

 // after change
onclick="getCota('Shakhtar' ,'meci',1)"
```

Comment: if I change to : <td><label id="'.$idConta1.'" onclick="getCota(\''.$row['id_meci'].'\',\''.$meci1.'\',1)" >' .$row['victorie_1'] . '</label></td> it only shows me that content of $row['victorie_1'], without $meci1...

Comment: #meci1 is a footbal match from db and $row['victorie_1'] one betting number and I want to show the name of the teams and next to them that number

Comment: Probably wrong quoting is not the only error, I would recommend to step through the code one line after the other. I assume `$(numeMeci).text()` should be `$('#' + numeMeci).text()` if thats an ID ...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly your issue, but you aren't specifying the `numeMeci` parameter in the last four columns. For example:

```
onclick="getCota('.$row['id_meci'].',2)" > // no second parameter
```

With it missing, your `getCota(id,numeMeci,index)` is receiving the index values in `numeMeci` instead of the `index` parameter. Effectively that function would be attempting something like:

```
$(2).text()
```

jQuery probably doesn't like that.

Comment: i specified numeMeci in the last forum columns to but it's still the same

Comment: although, this is what i get now : Uncaught ReferenceError: Shakhtar is not defined . Shakthar being one of the names that i want to get, and the same for all the other names

Comment: You must have a JavaScript error in one of your include files then. Use your browser's debugging console to track it down.